# Triggering Backbone.js delegated events from iframe

Tags: iframe, backbone.js, event-handling, event-delegation

I have a situation where I am loading an iframe inside of a backbone view. The view has an events hash that handles click events.

```
events: {
  'mousedown': 'toggleActive'
}
```

This works fine for the DOM that the view is part of. Problem is when I click inside the iframe DOM, the click event doesn't bubble up to the view (as expected). So I wrote some code that transfers the click from the iframe DOM to the parent DOM. I have the following inside the iframe body.

```
$("body").bind("click", function(event){
   window.parent.document.$("#"+tgId).trigger(event.type);
});
```

This works fine for regular jquery event handlers, but for some reason it doesn't trigger the view's event handlers (from the events hash).

Does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding a debugger statement inside your click handler, and then checking what `window.parent.document.$("#"+tgId)` actually is?  It's hard to say for sure, but my guess is that that code is not selecting the element you expect.  jQuery will then happily let you call trigger on an empty set, so you would't get any errors if that was the case.

Comment: it was the right one. and it was executing my jquery test handler which would turn the background of the element red.

Comment: Well, in that case it sounds like either: A) your view has the wrong element, or B) its event handling is being disrupted (eg. by calling `undelegateEvents`).  You can check the former with a `console.log` or `debugger` statement in your view, and you can check the later by checking the event binds directly.  If you do: `window.parent.document.$("#"+tgId).data("events") it will show you exactly what events are bound to that element.